# passing values using ajax post from view to controller in vb.net

Tags: ajax, vb.net, parameters

This is the ajax call in an aspx page which calls the function Save_RT_Threshold in controller.

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../Config/Save_RT_Threshold",
            data: "{'fname':'dave', 'lname':'ward'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert("Successfully Saved!!!");

            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert("failed");
            }
        });
```

The following is the Method in controller

```
 <WebMethod()> _
 Public Function Save_RT_Threshold(ByVal fname As String, ByVal lname As String) As String
        MsgBox("The value is : " & fname)
 End Function
```

while invoking the above method with ajax call, msgbox always displays null.

```
"The value is: ". The value of fname is null.
```

what is the problem in this method?

Answer (score 0):

the webmethod itself should be a Shared method.

Can you try like:

```
Public Shared Function Save_RT_Threshold(ByVal fname As String, ByVal lname As String) As String
        MsgBox("The value is : " & fname)
 End Function
```